# Nested Routing is not displaying the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, nested-routes

`I'm trying to display CollectionPage Component from ShopPage component as a nested route that receives match as a param but I get an empty page with an error.it is not rendering the collection page  from inside the shop page. These are my components`

**Shop page**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import CollectionsOverview from '../../components/collections-overview/collections-overview.component';
import CollectionPage from '../collection/collection.component';

const ShopPage = ({ match }) => (
    <div className='shop-page'>
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} element={<CollectionsOverview />} />
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:collectionId`} element={<CollectionPage />} />
    </div>
);

export default ShopPage;
```

**CollectionPage Component :**

```
import React from "react";
import CollectionItem from "../../components/collection-item/collection-item.component";
import './collection.styles.scss';

const CollectionPage= ({ match }) => {
    console.log();
    return (
        <div className="category">
            <h2>CATEGORY PAGE</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CollectionPage;
```

i am trying to render the Collectionpage  from inside of shoppage using nested routing but i am getting error while i go to shop  shop.component.jsx:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Answer (score 1):

Since you're passing `collectionId` in Route from ShopPage to CollectionPage component , you have to add `match.params.collectionId` inside CollectionPage to obtain the Id.

Also i've added `collectionId.toUpperCase()` so that you can see id in display.

```
const CollectionPage= ({ match }) => {
    const collectionId = match.params.collectionId;
    return (
        <div className="category">
            <h2>{collectionId.toUpperCase()} PAGE</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Give this one a try and let me know , if you're able to obtain the `collectionId`.

Comment: Its still showing error that path is not defined on  `<Route exact path={`${match.path}`} element={<CollectionsOverview />} /> `  Here is the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
    at ShopPage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2650:22)`

Comment: can you shoe me you main routes component ?

Comment: Main Routes are in App.js  `<div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path='/shop' element={<ShopPage />} />
          <Route exact path='/checkout' element={<Checkout />} />

          <Route
            exact
            path='/signin'
            element={
              this.props.currentUser ? (
                <Navigate to='/' />
              ) : (
                <SignInAndSignUpPage />
              )
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );`

Comment: its hard to read this , can you dump your code in codesandbox and provide the link

Comment: I solved problem by downgrading the node package manager